# "cannot pull into a repository with state: merging_resolved"

Tags: git, merge, egit

After some pulling, merging and conflict resolving, my GIT is stuck. This is what I tried to do (with EGit) on the main project:

- "Pull" returns "cannot pull into a repository with state: merging_resolved"
- "Fetch from upstream" returns "No ref to fetch from GeniusWebSocket - origin - everything up to date."
- "Merge" is greyed in the menu.
- "Commit" returns "Commit/amend not possible...".
- "Push to upstream" returns "rejected - non-fast-forward".
- "Add to index" does nothing.

Near the project title, I see [Merged master up-arrow 1 down-arrow 1].

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: What does `git status` tell you?

Comment: Anyone else thinks GIT is a failure? I've been using it for over a year and still fear PULL - time to try Mecurial.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since you have finished your merge, and if you don't have any pending changes, you can try a `git reset --hard`, and see if the issue persists.
(See [EGit reset your current HEAD](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Resetting_your_current_HEAD))

---

[Ankit Marothi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3611104/ankit-marothi) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271906/cannot-pull-into-a-repository-with-state-merging-resolved/16273416#comment87044382_16273416):

> I resolved it by resetting it from egit, using `Team->Reset` and using `mixed reset` as the option.

Comment: I resolved it by resetting it from egit, using Team->Reset and using mixed reset as the option.

Comment: @AnkitMarothi Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem . I did a project import in between of resolving conflicts that appeared after doing a pull.

I solved it by following steps:
1. Right click on repository and click on Reset
2. I selected a branch under Remote Tracking on which there was most recent changes
3. did a MIXED Reset Type

Finally, I got all the latest version with my changes in unstaged version.

Answer (score 1):

If working in eclipse IDE. goto -> `Git Staging` view -> commit & push, if you see there is a commit message already.

If you don't see any commit message there, synchronize your repository and go back to check it again.