# How to resolve Git merge conflict when checking in new code into an empty Bitbucket repository

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

Before I post my question, I want to mention that I asked this question in another Stack Exchange site and was told this question needed to be asked in Stack Overflow.

I recently created a new repository in Bitbucket where I intended to check in a new project I have been working on for some time. When I created the new project in Bitbucket, I selected the option to include a `.gitignore` file. When I tried to push my new project, it resulted in a conflict with this file that I have not been able to resolve. Currently, my code is stuck in my local repository.

---

### What I have tried

1. I tried to mark the .gitignore as merged in Eclipse. I got this error: *Cannot pull into a repository with state: MERGING*. I then executed *git merge --abort* as suggested in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31050617/2851311).

```
error: Entry '.gitignore' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.
```

2. After the above error, I tried a hard reset (from Eclipse). Then I tried the abort again (from item 1 above. That resulted in the following error:

```
fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).
```

3. Then, I tried to do a pull from Git Bash which resulted in:

```
$ git pull
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

4. Tried to remove .gitignore by running *git rm .gitignore* and then call *git pull*. I got the following error:

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

---

As you can see, I tried to fix from Git Bash and from Eclipse, but I have not been able to make any progress. I don't care losing the information on the .gitignore file. I can always recreate the file. I just need to resolve this conflict by any means necessary so that I can push the stuff in my local repo to the remote one. I am at a loss.

Comment: Would simply deleting the (basically empty) Bitbucket repo and starting over be an option?

Comment: What does `git status` say for your local repository?

Comment: @chepner It is an option. Would that affect the status of the local repo?

Comment: @8bittree It says that `.gitignore` is unstaged as well as other files that are contained in the `.gitignored` file.

Comment: Right now, there appears to be *no* relationship between your local repo and the Bitbucket repo.

Comment: @chepner I would like to know if there is another alternative, in case this ever happens when connected to an existing repo and deleting it in Bitbucket is not an alternative. I have never encountered such a persistent issue like this one.

Comment: Typically, you pull the remote down, merge locally, then push the changes back. I don't know if there's a clean way to fix this during the push (when the merge takes place on Bitbucket).

Comment: @chepner I hear you. I had been able to resolve similar conflicts in the past. This one has blown my mind. I was considering what you proposed of simply deleting the remote and connect my local to a new one, but I want to know if there is another way to accomplish the same without such "drastic" method. I am no expert in Git, so I decided to ask the community. Frankly, I don't see another way out and your initial suggestion leads me more to believe it even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

If you just want to override the `.gitignore` on Bitbucket, consider using `git push --force` to discard the initial Bitbucket commit entirely.

If you want to *keep* that file, grab it out of that commit:

```
git show origin/master:.gitignore > ignore.bitbucket
```

for instance, then incorporate the file however you like, and *then* use a force-push to discard the (single) Bitbucket commit.

## Long

Here's the root of the problem:

> When I created the new project in Bitbucket, I selected the option to include a `.gitignore` file.

Git is not about *files*, and hence does not store *files*—at least not in the sense you're probably thinking of.  What Git is about, and what Git therefore stores, is *commits*.<sup>1</sup>  Commits—but not branch names—can be related via ancestry: in the same way that most humans have two parents, most commits have a single parent.  So some commit can be the great-great-great-grand-child of some other commit, for instance, or two commits might be siblings (both have the same parent), or other similar relationships.

(These relationships form a *Directed Acyclic Graph* or [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).  The commit graph in particular allows Git to find common ancestors of two branch-tip commits.)

The commits themselves, which we have Git find by their hash IDs, each hold two things:

- Each commit holds a full snapshot of every file, in a compressed and read-only format with the contents de-duplicated (across all commits).  These snapshots are like tar or rar or winzip archives; they need to be extracted before you can actually use the files (and then the extracted files *are not in Git* at that point, though there is obviously a *copy* that *is* in Git: it's just stored in this compressed and de-duplicated Git-ified format).
- Each commit also stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit.  The metadata includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit, for instance, along with a date-and-time-stamp showing when they made the commit.  In this metadata, Git adds, for its own commit-graph purposes, the raw hash IDs of a list of *previous* commits—usually just one, so that Git has to walk backwards one commit at a time, from the latest commit to the second-latest, to the third latest, and so on.

Users, of course, want their files.  The files are in the commits, in their stored-for-all-time archives.  We must therefore pick some commit and have Git extract that commit, so that we can see and work with some files.

If you have Bitbucket (or any other web hosting site) make a new, totally-empty repository, it will have no commits in it yet.  That's fine, but if and when you *clone* this empty repository, you will get a warning: Git will say that there was nothing for it to check out (which is true!).  This means if you make your own new, totally-empty repository, your new empty repository has the same lack-of-commits as your Bitbucket repository: the two are completely identical, in that both have nothing at all.

You can then make your own first commit, in your own repository, on your laptop or wherever it is stored.  Being the first commit ever, this commit will have *no* parent commit.  It *can't* have a parent, as there is no earlier commit, so it *doesn't* have a parent, and everything is fine.  This commit is slightly special though, and Git will tell you that you have made a—or "the"—*root* commit:

```
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) c5f8984] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README.txt
```

But you didn't do that: you had Bitbucket create a repository and then *create its own root commit* **in** that repository, so that *their* repository is not empty.  Their first commit contains a `.gitignore` file (and perhaps nothing else, or perhaps a README and/or LICENSE file; those are the typical GitHub options).

If you go on and make a root commit in your own initially-empty new repository, these two root commits are *not related*.  They are not parent-and-child.  They are not siblings, with a common parent.  They are completely unrelated.

I use the terms *your Git* and *their Git* as shorthand here to refer to your Git software working with your repository and their Git software working with their repository.  When you cross-connect two Gits like this, one of them is a sender and one is a receiver, and the sender will send some or all of his commits to the receiver, if the receiver doesn't have them yet.  That's how we *synchronize* two repositories, especially when one was a clone of the other at some point.

Cloning copies *all of the commits* (and none of the branches, sort of), so a clone made at some point in some repository's lifetime will start out with the same commits as the original, and any *added* commits will generally have some sort of ancestry-relationship.  But again, this doesn't quite work with an *empty* repository, since there's no initial commit.

So, what happened in this case is that after you set up the remote, you had your Git call up their Git and get, from them, their root commit that contains a `.gitignore` file.  Meanwhile you had your own root commit that contains a `.gitignore` file.

It's not clear to me exactly what happened in Eclipse (Eclipse has its own Java-based Git implementation that doesn't quite do the same things as the C based implementation you get with command-line Git from bash or other shells).  However, it left you in a weird state, which you fixed up, sort of, with your `git rm` command.  At this point `git pull` from bash ran:

1. `git fetch`: any `git pull` always runs this first.  This `git fetch` had nothing to do though, as you'd already obtained the Bitbucket root commit.
2. `git merge`: the `git pull` command means—is shorthand for—*run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command* and the default second Git command is `git merge`.

For `git merge` to *work*, it needs to find the best common ancestor between two *tip* commits.  To describe this properly we need some annotations.

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, a Git repository consists of two databases, one holding commits and other internal Git objects, and one holding names.  The two databases are simple [key-value stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), with the objects database keyed by hash ID, allowing Git to retrieve the raw object contents by hash ID, and the names database pairing individual *refs*—branch names, tag names, and other such names—with a single hash ID.

---

#### Drawing branches in Git

As I mentioned above, each commit is a two-part entity, holding metadata (information about the commit) and data (the snapshot archive, in the Git-ified format).  Each commit has a unique<sup>2</sup> hash ID.  To *draw* this, in a format suitable for human comprehension, we need to drop a lot of irrelevant detail, keeping just two things:

- a name for each commit, and
- the arrows coming out of the commit that form the arcs in the directed graph.

The result very often looks something like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H`, on the right, stands in for our *latest* commit's hash ID.  Commit `H` has metadata that include the raw hash ID of an earlier commit, which we'll call `G`.  Commit `G` has metadata with the hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`, and so on.  By holding each previous-commit hash ID, the commit can be said to "point to" the earlier commit.

To quickly find any particular commit—in our case, our latest commit `H`—Git uses a branch name like `master` or `main`, or a tag name like `v1.2`, or some other name like `origin/master`.  This name contains the raw hash ID of the actual commit, so it too can be said to "point to" a commit:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

What makes a *branch* name special in Git is that you can *check out* or *switch to* some branch so as to extract the files from its latest commit.  Running `git switch main` here tells Git that you'd like to have, to see and work on/with, the contents of the files as they exist saved forever in commit `H`.  Git therefore *extracts* those files to a work area—your working tree—and, as soon as it has done that, *remembers which branch name you asked for*.  To remember the branch name, Git attaches the special name `HEAD`, which I draw like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

You can create new branch names at any time.  Each name must point to exactly one commit.  If you were to pick commit `G`, for instance, to create the new name `br1`, we would draw it this way:

```
...--G   <-- br1
      \
       H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

We're still "on" branch `main`, and still using the files from commit `H`, but now there's a direct way to find the hash ID of earlier commit `G`, rather than, e.g., running `git log` and finding the hash ID of `G` manually.  But most often, when we create a new branch name, we make it point to the *current* commit:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, main (HEAD)
```

We can now *switch to* that branch with `git switch br1`.  This attaches our `HEAD` to the name `br1`, and extracts the files from `H`—except we already have all the files from `H`, so Git doesn't bother doing anything at all, other than shuffling the attachment of `HEAD` here:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD), main
```

If we now create a *new commit*, the new commit gets a new, unique hash ID.  We will call it "commit `I`" for simplicity.  New commit `I` will point back to the commit we were using when we *made* new commit `I`, i.e., commit `H`, and once Git has saved away all the files and metadata for new commit `I`, Git will write `I`'s hash ID into the *name* to which `HEAD` is attached:

```
          I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

If we make another new commit `J`, `J` will point backwards to `I`, and Git will write `J`'s hash ID into `br1`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

If we now switch back to `main`, Git will remove, from our work area, the files that go with `J`, and put in the files that go with `H` instead, and leave us with this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

We can now create and switch to a new branch `br2`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2 (HEAD), main
```

and as we make more commits, now `br2` will get updated:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

That, in a nutshell, is how Git branches really work: we *add commits* to them and they grow, and the *branch name* always means *the last commit on the branch*.

Git allows us to move, or even delete, any branch name at any time (although you're not allowed to delete the one HEAD is attached-to; you have to switch away from it first).  If we move the name `br2` back one step to commit `K`, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K   <-- br2 (HEAD)
           \
            L   ???
```

We won't look at *how* we do this, here, we'll just note that commit `L` still exists—but now you can't *find* it, unless you memorized its random-looking hash ID.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>2</sup>The unique hash ID is the real key to making Git work.  The hash ID is unique across *every* commit in *every* repository, so that if two Gits meet, and compare hash IDs, they have the same hash ID if and only if they have the *same commit*, which they must have gotten by fetching or pushing (or during the initial clone, which is mostly one big fetch).

<sup>3</sup>Git has ways to get commit `L` back again, but if you leave it *unreachable* like this for more than a month or so, Git may get around to deciding that you don't care about it, and remove it for real.  So commits are not *always* forever, but removing them is tricky: you arrange for Git not to *see* them—to have no names that let you and Git *find* them—and then eventually they will go away, unless they got sent to some *other* Git that decides to hang on to them.

Because Git is very greedy for new commits, once you've *sent* a commit somewhere else, it is very hard to get rid of for real.  If you think of commits like viruses for which there is no vaccine, you're not far off.

---

#### Merging

Git has a lot of things that `git merge` will do that *aren't* merges, but to understand them and Git, it's best to start with the kind of `git merge` that *is* a full-blown merge.  Suppose we have:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

from before.  We're on `br1`, using commit `J`—our working tree has the files from `J`—and we decide we'd like to *combine* our work on `br1` with the work someone did—maybe that was us, maybe it was someone else; Git won't really care, as Git only cares about *commits*.  So we run:

```
git merge br2
```

Git will find not one or two but *three* commits.  Git starts with our current commit `J`, which is easy to find: *read `HEAD`, look up the branch name, that's the hash ID*, and with the other commit we mention, which is also easy to find: *see the name `br2`, look up the branch name, that gives hash ID `L`*.  So `J` and `L` are the two *tip* commits to merge.

But: in order to find *work done*, Git has a bit of a problem.  Commits hold *snapshots*.  To see *changes*, Git has to *compare* two snapshots.  What snapshots can Git compare?  Some people think Git will compare `J` and `L` directly, but that doesn't work.  Suppose some file in `J` is different from its counterpart in `L`.  Did *we* change it, or did *they* change it?  Or maybe we *both* changed it.  We're back to that question of *what the heck does it mean to change a file* when all the commits hold *snapshots*.

But suppose we work *backwards* from `J`.  Moving back one hop we find commit `I`, which *isn't* on branch `br2`, but moving back *two* hops we find commit `H`, which *is* on `br2`.  Likewise, moving back two hops from `L`, we land on `H`, which *is* on `br1`.  So commit `H` is on *both branches*.  That makes it a candidate.  Git uses a particular algorithm here to find the *best* merge base commit,<sup>4</sup> and in this case, always finds `H`.

Git then runs *two* diff operations, one from `H` to `J` to find out what we *changed*, and one from `H` to `L` to find out what *they* changed.  The two diffs tell Git which lines of which files *we* changed, and which lines of which files *they* changed.  By adding these two sets of changes together, Git may—and often is—able to combine the changes.  Git then applies the combined changes to the files in the merge base.  Depending on how you like to look at it, this keeps our changes while adding theirs, or keeps their changes while adding ours.

If Git *is* able to do this combining all on its own, `git merge` will make a new commit as usual, with one special feature.  The new commit will have a snapshot as usual.  It will have metadata as usual as well, listing us as the author and committer and "now" as the date-and-time-stamps.  The merge commit can have a log message where we explain *why* we made the merge, and the merge commit has a list of previous commit hash IDs.  Once the new merge commit is written out, Git updates the current branch name as usual, too.

The *only* thing special about this new merge commit is that its list of previous commits doesn't just list the *current* commit `J`.  It also lists the commit we said to merge, i.e., commit `L`.  So the updated graph looks like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

That's the basics of `git merge`.  (All the complications come in with things like merge conflicts, and options that tell Git not to actually merge after all, or force Git to do a real merge even if Git would *default* to not bothering to merge.  We won't cover any of this here.)

---

<sup>4</sup>The algorithm in question is the [Lowest Common Ancestor one, modified for directed graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs).  There may be multiple LCAs in some complex graphs; this answer does not cover this case.

---

#### Your case gives Git heartburn because of disjoint subgraphs

In your case, you have, in your own repository, one or more commits—I'll just draw one—and a branch name pointing to the last of these:

```
A   <-- main (HEAD)
```

plus one more commit obtained from the Bitbucket Git, with a remote-tracking name (`origin/main` or `origin/master`; I'm using `main` here):

```
B   <-- origin/main
```

You're now asking Git to combine these two root commits:

```
A   <-- main (HEAD)

B   <-- origin/main
```

Git works backwards from `A` and ... oops, there's nothing there.  Git works backwards from `B` and, again, oops!  *There is no best common ancestor.*

The output from `git merge`, at this point, is:

> ```
> fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
> ```

because there's no common ancestor.

Git *used to* just fake one up (in Git versions before 2.9).<sup>5</sup>  If Git simply *pretends* that there's a common pre-root commit `ε` and makes things look like this:

```
  A   <-- main (HEAD)
 /
ε
 \
  B   <-- origin/main
```

then suddenly the general merge algorithm works.  But what files are in this fake epsilon-commit `ε`?  The answer is: none at all.  That means that each file in `A` is completely new, and each file in `B` is also completely new.  You'll often get an "add/add conflict" from this kind of merge and have to resolve the conflict manually.

To tell Git that you'd like to do that, use the `--allow-unrelated-histories` option to `git merge`.  This emulates the pre-2.9 behavior.  Once you resolve any conflicts, if needed, and finish the merge, you end up with a graph like this:

```
A--C   <-- main (HEAD)
  /
 B   <-- origin/main
```

which has two root commits.  Commits `A` and `B` remain unrelated, but commit `C` has two parents, `A` and `B`, and hence you can `git push` commit `C` to a repository that has its own `main` pointing to commit `B`.

There's nothing *good* about having two root commits in a repository.  It's not *wrong*, but it may confuse those who are not up on their graph theory.  It's probably best to avoid this as long as it's easy, and give the description of your initial setup, it *is* easy.

---

<sup>5</sup>My guess here is that Eclipse is doing this too, so that you didn't get an "unrelated histories" error in Eclipse, but instead got some merge conflict(s).  You might also not have made your own root commit yet, at that point.

Comment: Very nice answer. Thanks.

Comment: torek, this is the gift that keeps on giving. LOL I can screw up with confidence now, I just solved another issue thanks to  your answer.